# How to compute the coefficients (ODE using power series method)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

How to Solve $xy'+2y=4x^2;y(1)=5$ using power series method?

I've assumed $y = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m\implies y' = \sum_{m=1}^\infty m a_mx^{m-1}$.

Putting these values in  equation in $xy'+2y=4x^2$,we get

$x\sum_{m=1}^\infty ma_mx^{m-1} +2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m=4x^2 $

$\implies \sum_{m=1}^\infty ma_mx^{m} +2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_mx^m + 2a_0=4x^2  $

$\implies \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m(m+2)x^{m} + 2a_0 =4x^2  $

I'm not getting how to compute coefficient $a_m?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ODE has a regular singularity in $x=0$, if you want a series expansion around this point, you need the more general power series
$$
y(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^{m+r}
$$
and determine $r$ so that a non-zero value for $a_0$ is possible.

---

For an expansion around the regular point $x=1$, you need to also center the power series there,
$$
y(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m(x-1)^m,~~a_0=y(1)=5.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty ma_m[(x-1)+1](x-1)^{m-1}+2\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m(x-1)^m=4[(x-1)^2+2(x-1)+1]
$$
so that comparing coefficients
$$
(m+2)a_m+(m+1)a_{m+1}=
\begin{cases}
4,&m=0,\\
8,&m=1,\\
4,&m=2,\\
0,&m>2.
\end{cases}
$$

---

You should find the same coefficients as in the expansion of 
$$
y(x)=x^2+4(1+(x-1))^{-2}=(x-1)^2+2(x-1)+1+4\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^mm(x-1)^m
$$

Comment: :See the edit.....